# I don't understand why empty() is returning true here

Tags: php

```
var_dump($r);
echo '<br /><br />';
echo $r[0]['minID'];
echo '<br /><br />';
echo empty($r);
```

This is the output:

```
array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["minID"]=> string(2) "16" } } 

16

1
```

Can anyone explain this to me, I have to be missing something, I've been using empty for years and I've never seen it return true for a non-empty array.

Edit:

output of php --version

```
PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Feb 22 2013 02:51:11)
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
```

This is on CentOS 6.4

Edit:

Figured it out, I'm a jackass.  I had several echo statements, and the last one was returning true legitimately.  Because I wasn't casting to int, the false wasn't showing and I was misinterpreting where the 1 was coming from.

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce it with `$r = [["minID" => "16"]];`.

Comment: [It outputs 0 for me, for over 80+ PHP versions](http://3v4l.org/Zd2h3).

Comment: Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: yep, that's why I'm so confused.  The code is literally copy/pasted, there is no interpretation here.  Everything I know about PHP tells me it shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: Couldn't reproduce it either http://codepad.org/T4btR4hk.

Comment: Can we see more of your code, or at least how `$r` is assigned?

Comment: read my edit, it was a PEBKAC issue.  I know better too, silly mistake.